Using a different chain, i.e., create_retrieval_chain in custom tools due to RetrievalQA deprecation
I am using RetrievalQA to define custom tools for my RAG. According to the official documentation, RetrievalQA will be deprecated soon, and it is recommended to use other chains such as create_retrieval_chain. Could you provide guidance on the correct way to use create_retrieval_chain in custom tools? I am currently encountering errors.
I am copying below the example code available as part of the official documentation.
from langchain.chains import RetrievalQA
from langchain_community.document_loaders import PyPDFLoader
from langchain_community.vectorstores import FAISS
from langchain_core.tools import Tool
from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI, OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain_text_splitters import CharacterTextSplitter
from langchain.agents import AgentType, initialize_agent
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

class DocumentInput(BaseModel):
    question: str = Field()

llm = ChatOpenAI(temperature=0, model="gpt-3.5-turbo-0613")

tools = []
files = [
    # https://abc.xyz/investor/static/pdf/2023Q1_alphabet_earnings_release.pdf
    {
        "name": "alphabet-earnings",
        "path": "/Users/harrisonchase/Downloads/2023Q1_alphabet_earnings_release.pdf",
    },
    # https://digitalassets.tesla.com/tesla-contents/image/upload/IR/TSLA-Q1-2023-Update
    {
        "name": "tesla-earnings",
        "path": "/Users/harrisonchase/Downloads/TSLA-Q1-2023-Update.pdf",
    },
]

for file in files:
    loader = PyPDFLoader(file["path"])
    pages = loader.load_and_split()
    text_splitter = CharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=1000, chunk_overlap=0)
    docs = text_splitter.split_documents(pages)
    embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()
    retriever = FAISS.from_documents(docs, embeddings).as_retriever()

    # Wrap retrievers in a Tool
    tools.append(Tool(args_schema=DocumentInput,name=file["name"],
            description=f"useful when you want to answer questions about {file['name']}",
            func=RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(llm=llm, retriever=retriever),))

agent = initialize_agent(agent=AgentType.OPENAI_FUNCTIONS,tools=tools,llm=llm,verbose=True,)

agent({"input": "User;s Question"})

I have incorporated the create_retrieval_chain as below, but I am getting an error.
tools = []
system_prompt = ("Use the the provided context to answer the question. If you don't know the answer, please state that you don't know."
"Keep the answer to-the-point and concise and use three sentence maximum."
"Context: {context}"
"Question: {input}")
        # Create a chat prompt template
        prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages([("system", system_prompt), ("human", "{input}"), ])# User's question        
        # Create the question-answering chain
        question_answer_chain = create_stuff_documents_chain(llm, prompt)
        retrieval_chain = create_retrieval_chain(retriever, question_answer_chain)

        tools.append(Tool(args_schema=DocumentInput,name=file["name"],
                description=f"useful when you want to answer questions about {file['name']}",
                func=retrieval_chain))

Error Log:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValidationError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 71
     68     question_answer_chain = create_stuff_documents_chain(llm, prompt)
     69     retrieval_chain = create_retrieval_chain(retriever, question_answer_chain)
---> 71     tools.append(Tool(
     72             args_schema=DocumentInput,
     73             name=file["name"],
     74             description=f"useful when you want to answer questions about {file['name']}",
     75             func=retrieval_chain
     76         ))
     78     print(f'{file["name"]} loaded and a new collection {collection_name} created successfully! \n')
     79 else:

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\CSVpython311\Lib\site-packages\langchain_core\tools.py:671, in Tool.__init__(self, name, func, description, **kwargs)
    667 def __init__(
    668     self, name: str, func: Optional[Callable], description: str, **kwargs: Any
    669 ) -> None:
    670     """Initialize tool."""
--> 671     super(Tool, self).__init__(  # type: ignore[call-arg]
    672         name=name, func=func, description=description, **kwargs
    673     )

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\CSVpython311\Lib\site-packages\pydantic\main.py:341, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.__init__()

ValidationError: 1 validation error for Tool
func
  bound=RunnableAssign(mapper={
  context: RunnableBinding(bound=RunnableLambda(lambda x: x['input'])
           | VectorStoreRetriever(tags=['Chroma', 'OpenAIEmbeddings'], vectorstore=<langchain_community.vectorstores.chroma.Chroma object at 0x0000020DB54AE850>), config={'run_name': 'retrieve_documents'})
})
| RunnableAssign(mapper={
    answer: RunnableBinding(bound=RunnableBinding(bound=RunnableAssign(mapper={
              context: RunnableLambda(format_docs)
            }), config={'run_name': 'format_inputs'})
            | ChatPromptTemplate(input_variables=['context', 'input'], messages=[SystemMessagePromptTemplate(prompt=PromptTemplate(input_variables=['context', 'input'], template="Use the mentioned description for this tool and the provided context to answer the question. If you don't know the answer, please state that you don't know.For questions related to Elm company, please note that 'Elm Company' is the updated name for 'AL ELM INFORMATION SECURITY COMPANY.' Both names can be used interchangeably to retrieve information.Keep the answer to-the-point and concise and use three sentence maximum.Context: {context}Question: {input}")), HumanMessagePromptTemplate(prompt=PromptTemplate(input_variables=['input'], template='{input}'))])
            | ChatOpenAI(client=<openai.resources.chat.completions.Completions object at 0x0000020DB463B450>, async_client=<openai.resources.chat.completions.AsyncCompletions object at 0x0000020DB4C739D0>, model_name='gpt-4', temperature=1.0, model_kwargs={'top_p': 0.7}, openai_api_key=SecretStr('**********'), openai_proxy='')
            | StrOutputParser(), config={'run_name': 'stuff_documents_chain'})
  }) config={'run_name': 'retrieval_chain'} is not callable (type=type_error.callable; value=bound=RunnableAssign(mapper={
  context: RunnableBinding(bound=RunnableLambda(lambda x: x['input'])
           | VectorStoreRetriever(tags=['Chroma', 'OpenAIEmbeddings'], vectorstore=<langchain_community.vectorstores.chroma.Chroma object at 0x0000020DB54AE850>), config={'run_name': 'retrieve_documents'})
})
| RunnableAssign(mapper={
    answer: RunnableBinding(bound=RunnableBinding(bound=RunnableAssign(mapper={
              context: RunnableLambda(format_docs)
            }), config={'run_name': 'format_inputs'})
            | ChatPromptTemplate(input_variables=['context', 'input'], messages=[SystemMessagePromptTemplate(prompt=PromptTemplate(input_variables=['context', 'input'], template="Use the mentioned description for this tool and the provided context to answer the question. If you don't know the answer, please state that you don't know.For questions related to Elm company, please note that 'Elm Company' is the updated name for 'AL ELM INFORMATION SECURITY COMPANY.' Both names can be used interchangeably to retrieve information.Keep the answer to-the-point and concise and use three sentence maximum.Context: {context}Question: {input}")), HumanMessagePromptTemplate(prompt=PromptTemplate(input_variables=['input'], template='{input}'))])
            | ChatOpenAI(client=<openai.resources.chat.completions.Completions object at 0x0000020DB463B450>, async_client=<openai.resources.chat.completions.AsyncCompletions object at 0x0000020DB4C739D0>, model_name='gpt-4', temperature=1.0, model_kwargs={'top_p': 0.7}, openai_api_key=SecretStr('**********'), openai_proxy='')
            | StrOutputParser(), config={'run_name': 'stuff_documents_chain'})
  }) config={'run_name': 'retrieval_chain'})

I tried defining a custom chain that uses create_retrieval_chain. This chain was used as a replacemnt to RetrievalQA.


According to the docs, when creating the Tool, the class constructor expects parameter func to be a function. What you're inserting now is a chain. Try to use func=retrieval_chain.invoke instead.
